May we have a sandbox thread in Discussions?
There are various "sandbox" questions and chat rooms across the network to let users experiment with formatting and features, or prepare drafts, in a designated location, to reduce the amount of disruption to regular activity on the site.
I'd like to create a sandbox thread in Discussions, to experiment with how it works, and understand its post types and threading model. However a discussion moderator expressed concern that given the poor quality of the tools they have for searching and moderating discussions, a sandbox discussion thread could create noise that distracts from the posts which actually need attention.
I concede that it might be a bit more disruptive than other sandboxes for the reason that it's on the main site, not a meta (since discussions isn't enabled on meta), but I don't think the amount of disruption would be that significant. To the extent that it's a problem, any activity in discussions would be a problem, and there's no way to prevent that short of shutting down the entire feature. However, given moderator concerns, I'd like to ask the question here and see how others feel.
Is it reasonable to create a sandbox thread in Discussions?

I'd rather [so] fix discussions first before doing something like this, if I am honest. The lack of other features, such as downvotes, xommunity edits, spam control, and other basic features of the main site is a far bigger problem in Discussions.

I would rather Stack Overflow throw the baby (Discussions) out with the bath water. That baby can’t be saved.

If, and that's a big if, Discussions were to stay around and we had the most basic features (most importantly searching and filtering in this case), then this would be a valid request/action. Until then, having a sandbox will make moderation harder than it is by taking away attention from latest activities (the only way for us to monitor the space) and should not be created. p.s. we will post an answer if a consensus was reached amongst Discussions moderator. For now, I am enforcing this until it is otherwise deemed appropriate.

@ThomA just in case I was unclear: I’m not asking for any changes or action from the company. I’m just asking for approval to go create a post myself.

@M-- I don’t really understand the concern, but I’m not sure what discussion moderator tools look like. There aren’t that many discussion posts each day. Users can flag posts if there are issues. This won’t create that much additional volume, but in any case I’m not sure there should be a burden on you to scan ever new post yourself proactively, versus responding to flags. General site moderators generally aren’t expected to review every post on the site, they’re primarily expected to respond to issues when users flag them.

There are no tools whatsoever at the moment, we only get to see a page with flagged discussions; and not all the problematic posts are flagged (I recently cleared 102 discussions which were not suitable for the space, some of which were created months ago). Diamond mods have more tools at their disposal, even regular users have more than we do. That way older or newer posts won't get buried forever and there are avenues to moderate them somewhat easily compared to Discussions.

There are some changes on the horizon (such as the new API which was abused). Waiting to see where we land, and not making moderating this dumpster fire harder is not a huge ask. Soon, Discussions is either going to be history or the feature will be different. Testing it right now has no value besides 'having fun', and that doesn't trump the hurdles it causes, however minute you think that'd be.

"... that doesn't trump the hurdles it causes, however minute you think that'd be" - I can see why you'd be against testing on arbitrary posts, especially by uninvolved users, but what actual issues are caused by having a sandbox to mess with? You stated it takes "away attention from latest activities", but I'm unsure what that means in practice, aside from one spot on the Discussions list.

It's a beta feature... the entire discussions feature can be considered a sandbox in its current state, IMO. Just test it by using it normally. There aren't a whole lot of incoming discussions going on but enough to try out stuff no?

@Gimby you want to unleash these savage wild animals on real production data?

@starball heck yes!

I don't think that having single sandbox thread in Discussions would cause a problem. While posts are by default arranged by recent activity. It would still be a single post that wouldn't cause any additional clutter and it would be fairly easy to monitor that single post for potential spam. If necessary, I can create sandbox discussion to avoid further issues with flagging that post.

If I need discussions, I'll go reddit. I suggest next big projects on StackOverflow instead of clearing feature request lists here (it's booooring, sure): StackTitter (name is suggested by ChatGPT for a Twitter alternative here), StackPooTube (guess what)..

Yeah we must have a dedicated sandbox thread so we don't risk needlessly disturbing the day to day snake oil commercials and pornographic content of Discussions. On the other hand, a sandbox thread is a perfect place for them to post even more of said content - yay, everyone wins! Except maybe the people visiting the site to discuss programming, but nobody cares about them.

@Lundin No one needs to care about the people who go to Discussions to talk about programming, because they don't exist in any meaningful quantities. They go to reddit, another proper forum, or one of many various chat services instead, because SO decided to try to jump into an existing market in the most inefficient way possible

@SecurityHound If you don't like Discussions, don't use it. I consider it the most potentially valuable feature of the entire SE network. SO is deliberately letting it languish to undermine the idea that we need a place for opinion-based discussion.

@KevinKrumwiede - I don’t; I won’t keep my opinions about Discussions to myself, that’s how features like Discussions are rollout. I consider it the one feature if let to its own to my the sole reason users like myself will exit the community permanently. If I had a different opinion would you tell me to keep it to myself?

@SecurityHound How does the existence of Discussions detract from your experience on the rest of the site?

Why can’t I dislike something and say I dislike it? Discussions are essential unmoderated or impossible to moderate with the tools provided. Every single discussion should on the first 2 pages was (adult) spam. (I just looked)

@SecurityHound Disliking it is fine. Saying you'll quit the community because it exists is childish. Just don't look at it and it can't hurt you.

@KevinKrumwiede—I have been slowly moving away from Stack Overflow as it already was. Discussions are one of those features, like the AI integration, that result from not listening to the community. So, providing feedback, while strong in its language and suggesting I wouldn't say I like Discussions, is not childish since I am saying that with a mindset built on my decade of being a community member.  In recent years, this has very quickly transitioned to other communities because of features like Discussions, which are currently filled with content I don't feel comfortable viewing at home.

@KevinKrumwiede— So, perhaps instead of calling another user childish or asking them not to use a feature, we can find common ground to improve the bread-and-butter portion of the community. Or we can just bring back Stack Overflow Jobs, which isn't powered by the scam company Indeed. I can't believe I am actually being called childish for saying do not like Dicussions, and perhaps specifically saying, I feel like Discussions cannot be fixed.

@SecurityHound Discussions is what I've wanted for a decade, or would be if SO put some effort into improving it. (IMO, Discussions should have just been another SE.) I would understand Discussions making you want to leave SO if Discussions were diverting development effort from other parts of the site, but it isn't. They're clearly not putting any effort into improving Discussions at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79238102/79250757 - okay I changed my mind. The sandbox post was a good idea. Y'all are expert wreckers.

I created a Discussions Sandbox that can be used for experimenting.
I will monitor it for potential spam.
If any other issues come along when working with this sandbox, please ping me here (or anywhere else).

Thanks! I've added it to the list of sandboxes.

TL;DR: After discussing this internally and Dalija agreeing to monitor the sandbox so nothing goes wrong, we have created one.

As I explained in my comments, there aren't many tools available to us to monitor the space. Recent activity is the only way as of now; and to clarify, it is not only about a single entry in the list of Discussions, but also monitoring each thread and its replies (in my recent attempt at clearing up Discussions prior to posting this: Can Discussions be saved?, I have found multiple spam and AIGC replies from months ago which were not deleted nor flagged). That said, with a mod keeping an eye on the sandbox, there won't be any long-lasting issues.
I should also clarify that I don't consider Discussions to be a viable product as-is and think that the clock is running out on it. So why was I opposing the sandbox? I was not comfortable with imposing additional work on other mods who are still actively handling flags and monitoring the posts (while I mostly handle red/custom flags).

That's understandable. Thanks for the explanation.
